# What would be the easiest way to make my bitcoins into real us money?

Tags: transactions

I have zero knowledge on this subject, I did not buy into bitcoins I only played poker on a website that provided them for free and ended up gathering some bitcoins. What is the difference between different websites that allow you to convert them to us currency, what is the most safest way to do this? I need all the details.

Comment: Without knowing things like where you are located, this is going to be almost impossible to answer. A local Bitcoin meetup might be your best solution.

Answer (score 1):

https://localbitcoins.com/ will show real people to trade with (online or by cash). It has Feedback system so you can check the person you will trading with.

Answer (score 0):

There are several Bitcoin exchanges around, but Mt. Gox is the one I'd go for.
[image: Mt.Gox Bitcoin Exchange]
https://www.mtgox.com/

I suggest you read Mt.Gox's FAQ section, located here:

https://support.mtgox.com/forums/20105883-FAQ

Welcome to Bitcoin!